customizing the default name of the page when i save it as PDF file from printing page in oracle apex
I am working on the invoice printing page in Oracle Apex. This page is  PLSQL Dynamic content
It has a print button and when you click on it, it opens the print preview page. When you choose to save as pdf instead of printing the page , I want to change the default name to the invoice number that I am saving.
I tried to do that using javascript code inside the page but it doesn't work
this is the code i have used
htp.p('<!-- HTML Button or Link to open the invoice with inv_code -->
<a href="#" onclick="openInvoicePage(''P48_INV_CODE'');">View Invoice</a>

<script>
// Function to dynamically build the URL with inv_code
function openInvoicePage(inv_code) {
    // Construct the new URL with the inv_code
    var baseUrl = ''https://hekalit.oracleapexservices.com/apexdbl/r/hekalit22/ite-i-com-erp-for-emaar159/invoicepage/P48_INV_CODE'';
    var session = ''&APP_SESSION.'';
    var fullUrl = baseUrl + :P48_INV_CODE + ''?session='' + session;
    
    // Redirect to the constructed URL
    window.location.href = fullUrl;
}
</script>
 ');

can anyone help me?

I noticed that it takes a word (invoicepage) as a default name and it is present inside the URL
Is it possible to modify  it and add the invoice code next to the invoicepage?

Look for the page that generates the preview (invoicepage) and add an extra header before you send the BLOB to the user's browser.
htp.p('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="invoice.pdf"');

